# Move alternative implementations (SFINAE) of a method to seperate file

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have a class with a bool as a template parameter to control the behavior of the class (in my particular case it controls whether or not a cache is used for certain calculations). All methods not affected by this option are defined in the `.h` file and implemented in a `.tpp` file. Though, one methods implementation depends on the passed template parameter and I am unable to figure out how I can move its implementation to the seperate file as well. Currently I have something similar to this example.

MyClass.h

```
template<bool enableCache = false>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    void someMethod();

    template<bool fwd = enableCache, typename std::enable_if<fwd>::type* = nullptr>
    unsigned int calcSomething() {
        // ask cache if calculation is necessary
        return 0;
    }

    template<bool fwd = enableCache, typename std::enable_if<!fwd>::type* = nullptr>
    unsigned int calcSomething() {
        // always recalculate
        return 1;
    }
};

#include "MyClass.tpp"
```

MyClass.tpp

```
template<enableCache>
void MyClass<enableCache>::someMethod() {
    // do something
    return;
}
```

This setup works (unless I introduced some minor errors while simplifying my original code), but I want to move the implementation of `calcSomething` to the `.tpp` as well. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: why won't you provide two specializations in place of SFINAE? `template <> unsigned int MyClass<true>::calcSomething()` and `template <> unsigned int MyClass<false>::calcSomething()`

Comment: There's really no difference between the definition being in the header file, and being in a file included from the header file.

Comment: @Piotr Probably there is no reason and I confused myself with making things unnecessary complicated. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Barry I know. The question is more or less just asked out of curiosity (and to be consistent).

Comment: You can move this member into a base class or make it a static member of a struct specialized on the boolean template parameter. I am with @Barry, though.

Comment: @Piotr: I am always confused by this, so I might be wrong here... But are those even specializations? Aren't that explicit instantiations? (And are they even allowed for members?)

Comment: @sbi *"are those even specializations? "* yes, *"Aren't that explicit instantiations?"* `template unsigned int MyClass<true>::calcSomething();` is an explicit instantiation, *"And are they even allowed for members?"* yes, they are

Comment: @sbi explicit instantiation: `template unsigned int MyClass<true>::calcSomething();`

Comment: @sbi specialization: `template <> unsigned int MyClass<true>::calcSomething() { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @Piotr: Ah, now I got it! Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: Your solution is the cleanest in my situation, I guess. If you mind adding an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You could just forward to a non-template function:

```
unsigned int calcSomething() {
    return calcSomethingImpl(std::integral_constant<bool, enableCache>{});
}

unsigned int calcSomethingImpl(std::true_type /* enableCache */) {
    // ask cache if calculation is necessary
    return 0;
}

unsigned int calcSomethingImpl(std::false_type /* enableCache */) {
    // always recalculate
    return 1;
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with SFINAE at all, and non-template member functions are much easier to reason about than member function templates.

Moreover, you can have `MyClass<bool >` inherit from a non-template class, that provides the two `calcSomethingImpl`s are protected functions - which would let you define them in a source file instead of a header (if that was something you would like to do).

Comment: This simple trick uses overloading rather than SFINAE.  It's used extensively in the standard template library.  There is no additional runtime overhead by fowarding the call to the implementing function (this should be inlined away) and is much easier for junior developers to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. This solution requires the creation of a temporary `integral_constant` for every call, am I right?

Comment: In my particular case I like the solution suggested by Piotr a bit more but your answer is very interesting too. I really try to remember this pattern.

Comment: @Rambo: The `std::integral_constant<>` is just used as a tag to decide which overload to pick. I suppose it's an empty object, so inlining and optimization should be able to eliminate it. I'm with @Barry on this, it is probably the simplest solution.